# Server Fault is down; no update on stackstatus

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error, serverfault

When browsing Server Fault pages, I receive the **it's not you, it's me** error:

> **This is our fault**. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us.

and no information is available on the stack status webpage: https://stackstatus.net/ or from [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) on Twitter.

Comment: @Sonic the `.net` webpage shows a `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error in my browser. I thought it is not the official page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've solved the problem in the short-term. We're looking into the long-term solution.

We'll have a postmortem report when everything is completely fixed.  The short version was a lack of disk space but, of course, that's just part of the whole story.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Nick uploaded his holiday movies to the wrong server?

Comment: Looks like it's down again :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) is back up now.